# ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre estos dos métodos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Hace poco he descubierto el uso de la compresión de listas en python y tengo algunas dudas sobre ellas. Por ejemplo, existe alguna diferencia entre estos dos métodos:

```
from random import randrange

class Monstruos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.posibilidades = [
            {"pocima"    : "naranja"},
            {"goblin"    : "verde"},
            {"ghoul"     : "azul"},
            {"esqueleto" : "blanco"},
            {"Cofre"     : "morado"},
            {"dragón"    : "rojo"}
        ]

    def e_grupo(self, tamano):
        self.grupo_enemigo = []
        for i in range(tamano):
            a = randrange(7)
            self.grupo_enemigo.append(self.posibilidades[a])

    def e_grupo2(self, tamano):
        self.grupo_enemigo2 = [self.posibilidades[a] for a in range(tamano) ]
```

El primer método, e_grupo, crea una lista cuyos valores son diccionarios. El segundo método, e_grupo2, hace exatamente lo mismo, pero me queda la duda de si ambos resultados retornan enrealidad la misma tipo lista, por ejemplo. O si es mejor usar una u otra manera por algo en específico.

Gracias.

---

Acabo de notar que el segundo método tiene el fallo de que no incluye por ningún lado el método randrange(). Por lo que ambos métodos sí son diferentes, pero bueno, suponiendo que no exista el método randrage en el primer método, ¿habría alguna diferencia con lo que devuelven?

Comment: Serian equivalentes (si cambias `[a]` por `[radrange(7)]` en el segundo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

El método `e_grupo` lo que intenta hacer es dado un tamaño obtener una lista (`self.lista_enemigo`) con ese tamaño obteniendo aleatoriamente elementos del atributo `self.posibilidades` (una lista de diccionarios).

Para ello itera las veces determinadas por `tamaño` y en cada iteración pretende obtener un índice válido aleatorio (pseudoaleatorio realmente) usando `random.randrange` con (`a = randrange(7)`.

Luego usa ese índice para obtener el elemento de `self.posibilidades`  con`self.posibilidades[a]` y lo agrega a la lista `self.grupo_enemigo` mediante `self.grupo_enemigo.append(...)`.

Aquí tenemos un problema, `random.randrange` genera un entero aleatorio entre 0 y 7 (incluidos) pero`self.posibilidades` tiene 6 elementos (indices del 0 al 5), por lo que **se pueden generar índices no válidos**. Debería ser `random.randrange(5)` o mejor `random.randrange(len(self.posibilidades))` para no tener que preocuparnos por el tamaño de la lista.

Corrigiendo lo anterior podría quedar:

```
def e_grupo(self, tamaño):
    self.grupo_enemigo = []
    for _ in range(tamaño):
        a = randrange(len(self.posibilidades))
        self.grupo_enemigo.append(self.posibilidades[a])
```

Esto genera como se ha comentado una lista que es asignada al atributo de instancia  `self.grupo_enemigo` con elementos tomados de forma aleatoria de `self.posibilidades`, por ejemplo `monstruos.e_grupo(4)` puede generar algo así:

```
[{'goblin': 'verde'}, {'Cofre': 'morado'}, {'dragón': 'rojo'}, {'Cofre': 'morado'}]
```

El segundo método usa una sintaxis diferente para construir la lista, conocida como listas por compresión. Básicamente ofrecen una manera más concisa de crear listas a partir de alguna otra secuencia. La sintaxis es un par de corchetes rodeando una expresión seguida de un ciclo `for` que itera sobre algún iterable. El resultado es una nueva lista cuyos items salen del resultado de  evaluar la expresión en cada iteración del `for`. Además puede existir `for` anidados y condicionales.

Su uso más común es generar nuevas listas donde cada elemento es el resultado de operación aplicada a cada item de otro iterable o para crear una lista con solo algunos elementos de otra en función de si cumplen o no una condición determinada.Por ejemplo, imagina que tenemos una lista de números:

```
nums = [1 , 5, 6, 4, 3, 8, 7]
```

y queremos obtener otra lista con los impares solo de la lista anterior, usando compresión de listas podemos hacer:

```
impares = [n for n in nums if n % 2 != 0]
```

lo anterior es equivalente a:

```
impares = []
for n in nums:
    if n % 2 != 0:
        impares.append(n)
```

La lista por compresión es más concisa, aunque hay quien piensa que es menos legible (lo cual suele ser cierto cuando hay varios for anidados o múltiples condicionales). Pero además existe una diferencia importante en cuanto a eficiencia, las listas por compresión son más eficientes que su homólogo usando un `for` clásico y `list.append`. La razón principal es que se evita la llamada  y carga del método `append` usando un bytecode especial para agregar los nuevos elementos a la hora de construir la lista.

Obviamente la sintaxis de las lista por compresión es estricta como se ha comentado antes y hay cosas que no podemos usar, por ejemplo estamentos como `continue`, `pass`, `break` o asignaciones a variables (aunque esto último va a cambiar en Python 3.8). En el [enlace a la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) tienes múltiples ejemplos de listas por compresión con distintos grados de complejidad.

La misma sintaxis puede usarse para construir generadores (expresiones generadoras), diccionarios y conjuntos.

Dicho esto, el método `e_grupo2` sería equivalente a `e_grupo` si obtuviera los elementos de `self.posibilidades` de forma aleatoria, lo cual no hace como ya comentabas en la propia pregunta. Lo que intenta hacer es obtener los elementos desde el primero hasta el elemento con índice `tamaño - 1`. Si convertimos la lista por compresión a su homólogo usando `append`, sería:

```
def e_grupo2(self, tamaño):
    self.grupo_enemigo2 = []
    for a in range(tamaño):
        self.grupo_enemigo2.appedd(self.posibilidades[a])
```

lo cual tiene un grave problema igual que el primer método, tiene la potencialidad de indizar sobre índices inválidos. En este caso los indices los genera `range(tamaño)`, el cual genera indices en el rango 0 - `tamaño` (sin incluir este último). Si tamaño es menor o igual que 6 no hay problema, pero si tamaño es mayor generara indices que no existente en `self.posibilidades`.

Para que este método sea similar al primero deberíamos hacer uso de `randrange` igual que antes:

```
def e_grupo2(self, tamaño):
    self.grupo_enemigo2 = [self.posibilidades[randrange(len(self.posibilidades))] for _ in range(tamaño)]
```

Ahora si que ambos métodos hace exactamente lo mismo, solo varía la sintaxis y la comentada mayor eficiencia de las listas por compresión.

A pesar de todo lo anterior, existe una forma mucho más simple de hacer lo que haces estos métodos, usar [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.choices) (Python >= 3.6) o en su defecto [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
import random

# Python >= 3.6
def e_grupo(self, tamaño):
    self.grupo_enemigo2 = random.choices(self.posibilidades, k=tamaño)

# Python <= 3.6
def e_grupo(self, tamaño):
    self.grupo_enemigo2 = [random.choice(self.posibilidades) for _ in range(tamaño)]
```

Más simple, eficiente y sin tener que preocuparnos por índices válidos o no. Además `choices` tiene una característica muy útil y es que podemos asignar pesos a cada opción, modificando su probabilidad de ser elegido.